# Can't get GPS working on Moverio bt350 using Unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, epson

I am trying to get GPS coordinates on an Android 5.1 (Lollipop) (Epson moverio BT350 AR glasses) using Unity.

The `LocationService` command hangs on initializing.

I used the standard code provided by Unity's on-line documentation.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestLocationService : MonoBehaviour
{
    IEnumerator Start()
    {
        // First, check if user has location service enabled
        if (!Input.location.isEnabledByUser)
            yield break;

        // Start service before querying location
        Input.location.Start();

        // Wait until service initializes
        int maxWait = 20;
        while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
            maxWait--;
        }

        // Service didn't initialize in 20 seconds
        if (maxWait < 1)
        {
            print("Timed out");
            yield break;
        }

        // Connection has failed
        if (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Failed)
        {
            print("Unable to determine device location");
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            // Access granted and location value could be retrieved
            print("Location: " + Input.location.lastData.latitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.longitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.altitude + " " + Input.location.lastData.horizontalAccuracy + " " + Input.location.lastData.timestamp);
        }

        // Stop service if there is no need to query location updates continuously
        Input.location.Stop();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be a permission issue for location services on the device your connecting.   If not that, I would increase the timeout from 20 seconds you may not be waiting long enough for a response.

```
    int maxWait = 20; // increase this
    while (Input.location.status == LocationServiceStatus.Initializing && maxWait > 0)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        maxWait--;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Permission is granted on the device and I have increased the timeout. It just hangs when initializing. The device accesses the GPS sensor - not the google localization with wi-fi/cellular

Comment: UPDATE:I think the problem is that Unity for location service status automatically calls for “high accuracy” approach that mixes GPS and network - and this is not supported by Epson device, that uses only GPS. I was able to replicate the problem on other android devices if I disabled the use of network to make location more precise. So I would need to understand how to specify in Unity that the access to location is “device only” GPS sensor.

Comment: Hey, I don't know you still have that problem, but you should check the 'Low Accuracy Location' from player settings. This uses only GPS, however 'Input.location.isEnabledByUser' statement has been seen wrong although open in device. If I delete this statement then location give '0.0, 0.0 'result. So I really try everything, but cannot find a solution. Can you give any help or advice?